# how do I place a text above a type text box

Tags: html, css

Hi guys how do I place a text above a type text box, I'm trying to create a first name box with first name on top and a box below it I'll also add a placeholder. Please help

Answer (score 0):

See attached snippet.

```html
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Name">
    <br>
    Placeholder:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Placeholder">
```